# Gaussian blur that handles alpha transparency

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, filter, gaussian

I have been trying to implement an algorithm in C# for a gaussian blur that takes care of transparency. I tried the following two implementations, and each seems to give me different type of results. But neither takes into account the alpha channel.

http://code.google.com/p/imagelibrary/downloads/detail?name=ImageLibrary-source-1_2_4.zip&can=2&q=
http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/image-processing-in-c-sharp-smoothing-using-convolution/

My test image has a simple circle on a transparent background PNG.

Could somebody point me in the right direction to get the gaussian blur to work with images that have transparency ?
The only link i could find was a box blur.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6162/Gausian-and-Alpha-Blurring

Answer (score 4):

If you are using [premultiplied alpha](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2009/11/06/premultiplied-alpha.aspx) transparency, you can blur the alpha channel just like the RGB channels.

If your alpha is not premultiplied, you can get weird fringing artifacts.  To avoid that, you can try converting your image to premultiplied, filtering it, then converting it back.  There are pitfalls in this process, but the result will likely be better than naively smoothing a unmultiplied alpha image.

Comment: I am still trying to figure out how this will fit. The test image and effect i am looking for is exactly similar to the one from the codeproject box blur link. The premultiplication doesnt seem to have an effect for this case where the image is composed of either fully transparent pixels or fully opaque ones. Am not sure what i am missing here...

Comment: There is no guarantee of a problem -- it depends on what RGB color you have under the transparent regions.  If it is the same as the color outside the region, it should be fine.  But, if somebody substitutes a different image for which this is not the case, they might be surprised and annoyed at the results...

Answer (score 2):

You must multiply each RGB value with the alpha value and afterwards divide the result with the maximum possible alpha.

Let's say you want to average just three pixels:

```
newBlue = (
  src[-1].Blue * src[-1].Alpha + 
  src[0].Blue * src[0].Alpha + 
  src[1].Blue * src[1].Alpha ) / (255*3);
```

As you can see: if all three pixels are solid (alpha=255) then this calculation won't cange anything compared to ignoring the alpha channel (which is indeed what we want).

Here is a 3x3 convolution *without* alpha:

```
            for (var i = nWidth - 2; i > 0; i--)
            {
                n = ((((pT[-sourcePixelSize]*m.TL) + (pT[0]*m.TM) + (pT[sourcePixelSize]*m.TR) +
                       (pM[-sourcePixelSize]*m.ML) + (pM[0]*m.MM) + (pM[sourcePixelSize]*m.MR) +
                       (pB[-sourcePixelSize]*m.BL) + (pB[0]*m.BM) + (pB[sourcePixelSize]*m.BR) + 5)/m.Factor) + m.Offset);
                *pD = (byte) (n <= 0 ? 0 : n >= 255 ? 255 : n);
                pT += sourcePixelSize;
                pM += sourcePixelSize;
                pB += sourcePixelSize;
                pD += 4;
            }
```

Here is the eqvivalent *with* alpha:

```
            for (var i = nWidth - 2; i > 0; i--)
            {
                alphaSum = (pT[-4 + ao] + pT[ao] + pT[4 + ao] +
                            pM[-4 + ao] + pM[ao] + pM[4 + ao] +
                            pB[-4 + ao] + pB[ao] + pB[4 + ao] + 5)/9;
                n = alphaSum != 0
                        ? ((((pT[-4]*pT[-4 + ao]*m.TL) + (pT[0]*pT[ao]*m.TM) + (pT[4]*pT[4 + ao]*m.TR) +
                             (pM[-4]*pM[-4 + ao]*m.ML) + (pM[0]*pM[ao]*m.MM) + (pM[4]*pM[4 + ao]*m.MR) +
                             (pB[-4]*pB[-4 + ao]*m.BL) + (pB[0]*pB[ao]*m.BM) + (pB[4]*pB[4 + ao]*m.BR) + 5)/
                            (m.Factor*alphaSum)) + m.Offset)
                        : 0;
                *pD = (byte) (n <= 0 ? 0 : n >= 255 ? 255 : n);
                pT += 4;
                pM += 4;
                pB += 4;
                pD += 4;
             }
```

Comment: Please excuse me, but I am not able to follow the variables used in the code snippet. Could you help by explaining those? Is the constant 4 used for incrementing 4 bytes?

Comment: One pixel of ARGB is 4 bytes. The "ao" variable is "alpha offset" which has a different value when each of the R/G/B channels is beeing processed (three passes is being made for each pixel).