# Making a glow effect - Problems with alpha values

Tags: glsl, sfml, blur

I want to create a glow effect for my game. In order to keep this minimalistic let's say I want to glow an Image. :)

Starting with this one:

[image: default picture, no effect]

To get something like this:[image: desired output, picture with glow effect]

It's a three step way.

- save all bright pixels from the scene (= luminescence)
- Apply a blur effect on those pixels (= blur)
- draw original picture and the blur texture ontop (= assemble)

Step 1 and 3 are no Problem. The blur part just doesn't want to work correctly.

Before I explain further, here's my luminescence result: [image: the picture, but all darker pixels are transparent]
*(threshold = 0.67f)*

An now when I blur this, I get some unlucky results:[image]
This black edge comes from the fact, that *any* transparent color is black *`vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`*. It's not an unkown Problem within SFML/GLSL, and the suggestion was to use SFML's `sf::BlendMode` for this and multiply the `.rgb` value of the final pixel color in the fragment shader with its alpha value. So I did and now this my result:

[image: blurred, but overall too dark, especially the edges]

It's better, but definetely not good. The blur shader now also avarages out the surrounding pixels of the luminescence mask. After assembling it's just a blurry picture:

[image: Blurry Picture, not even close to resemble a glow effect].. I tried "fixing" this in the shader files by checking if the pixel's alpha is zero. This way I don't value them when avaraging out. But since sf::BlendMode is activated, I don't know how alpha behaves now - So I deactivated the blendmode but I still have weird results. (at the very of this question I provided the code and a result from this attempt)

---

none of my attempts to fix this work. I really could use some help here. Maybe I'm doing something fundamentally wrong in the shaders.. here's the full code -
If you want to compile it, make a folder resources with the 2 Fragment shaders and the [background.jpg](https://pixnio.com/architecture/city-downtown/urban-water-architecture-buildings-city-lights-evening) (in 1280x720).

*luminescence.frag*

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float threshold;

void main(void){
    vec3 current_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).rgb;
    vec4 pixel =  vec4(current_color.rgb, 0.0);
    float brightness = dot(current_color.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));
    if (brightness >= threshold){
        pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    }
    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

*boxblur.frag*

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float texture_inverse;
uniform int blur_radius;
uniform vec2 blur_direction;

void main(void){
    vec4 sum = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    for (int i = 0; i < blur_radius; ++i){
        sum += texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + (i * texture_inverse) * blur_direction);
        sum += texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - (i * texture_inverse) * blur_direction);
    }
    vec4 pixel = vec4(sum / (blur_radius * 2 + 1));
    pixel.rgb *= pixel.a;
    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

*main.cpp*

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

void run() {
    const sf::Vector2f SIZE(1280, 720);

    sf::Texture background_tex;
    background_tex.loadFromFile("resources/background.jpg");
    sf::Sprite background(background_tex);



    sf::Shader luminescence;
    luminescence.loadFromFile("resources/luminescence.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    luminescence.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    luminescence.setUniform("threshold", 0.67f);

    sf::Shader blur;
    blur.loadFromFile("resources/boxblur.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    blur.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    blur.setUniform("texture_inverse", 1.0f / SIZE.x);




    sf::RenderStates shader_states;
    shader_states.blendMode = sf::BlendMode(sf::BlendMode::One, sf::BlendMode::OneMinusSrcAlpha);



    sf::ContextSettings context_settings;
    context_settings.antialiasingLevel = 12;

    //draws background
    sf::RenderTexture scene_render;
    scene_render.create(SIZE.x, SIZE.y, context_settings);

    //draws luminescence and blur
    sf::RenderTexture shader_render;
    shader_render.create(SIZE.x, SIZE.y, context_settings);



    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SIZE.x, SIZE.y), "glsl fun", sf::Style::Default, context_settings);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        scene_render.clear();
        scene_render.draw(background);
        scene_render.display();


        //apply luminescence
        shader_states.shader = &luminescence;
        shader_render.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        shader_render.draw(sf::Sprite(scene_render.getTexture()), shader_states);
        shader_render.display();

        //apply two pass gaussian blur 3 times to simulate gaussian blur.
        shader_states.shader = &blur;
        float blur_radius = 30.0f;
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
            blur.setUniform("blur_radius", static_cast<int>(blur_radius));

            //vertical blur
            blur.setUniform("blur_direction", sf::Glsl::Vec2(1.0, 0.0));
            shader_render.draw(sf::Sprite(shader_render.getTexture()), shader_states);
            shader_render.display();

            //horizontal blur
            blur.setUniform("blur_direction", sf::Glsl::Vec2(0.0, 1.0));
            shader_render.draw(sf::Sprite(shader_render.getTexture()), shader_states);
            shader_render.display();

            //decrease blur_radius to simulate a gaussian blur
            blur_radius *= 0.45f;
        }

        //assembly
        window.clear();
        window.draw(sf::Sprite(scene_render.getTexture()));
        window.draw(sf::Sprite(shader_render.getTexture()));
        window.display();
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        run();
    }
    catch (std::exception e) {
        std::cerr << "caught exception - - - " << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

This is the boxblur.frag where I tried to exclude zero alpha values: (I removed `shader_states.blendMode = sf::BlendMode(sf::BlendMode::One, sf::BlendMode::OneMinusSrcAlpha);`on line 29 in main.cpp of course):

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float texture_inverse;
uniform int blur_radius;
uniform vec2 blur_direction;

void main(void){
    float div = 0.0;
    vec4 sum = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    vec4 temp_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    if (temp_color.a > 0.0){
        sum += temp_color;
        div += 1.0;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i < blur_radius; ++i){
        temp_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + (i * texture_inverse) * blur_direction);
        if (temp_color.a > 0.0){
            sum += temp_color;
            div += 1.0;
        }
        temp_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - (i * texture_inverse) * blur_direction);
        if (temp_color.a > 0.0){
            sum += temp_color;
            div += 1.0;
        }
    }
    vec4 pixel;
    if (div == 0.0){
        pixel = vec4(texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).rgb, 0.0);
    }
    else{
        pixel = vec4(sum / div);
    }
    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

Resulting in:
[image: mostly bright values. but too blocky and not smooth at all]

[I am using Visual Studio 2017 Community] - Thanks for any help!

Comment: Instead of checking for alpha>0, you must multiply each color with it's alpha and afterwards divide by the total alpha found in the local area. A lot of calculations... I have code for doing convolution effects with alpha channels. Have posted it here several times but nobody ever understands it.... :-/

Comment: @DanByström hey that sounds interesting, could you give me a link to your code?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10271092/64121

Comment: Oh yes I've seen this before and yes I don't understand it. `T` = Red, `M` = Green, `B` = Blue, `D` = Alpha? And what are the Suffixes  `L`, `M`, and `R`? I also don't understand the alpha offset.

Comment: That's because this is live optimized code intended to be fast instead of readable T/M/R stands for top, middle and bottom scan lines, because this is a 3x3 convolution. I have attempted an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I posted this question also on en.sfml-dev.org ([here](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=25019.0)) and [fallahn](https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?action=profile;u=6715) showed me the correct approach.
 Before tackling that, here are the picture results:

*Luminescence (threshold = 0.24f):*
[image: luminescence picture]

*Blur (4 layers):*
[image: blur]

*Assembled:*
[image: glowing picture]

Yay! The solution is to set all transparent pixels to solid black `vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` and than after they've been blurred, just add them ontop the Scene:

```
vec4 tex_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
vec4 add_color = texture2D(add_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
gl_FragColor = tex_color + add_color;
```

This way, if `add_color` is black ("transparent"), we add `tex_color + vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)` which results in no change!

This is great, because now you can ignore the alpha channel completely.

To understand why I find this so great, you can read this little rant here (feel free to skip it):

<sup>Without worrying about alpha you can ignore any `sf::BlendMode` like the confusing `sf::BlendMode::OneMinusSrcAlpha` which caused me headaches for 2 solid days. Try calculating any reasonable "true" alpha value when you know they are all premultiplied. Of course you also have to multiply *all* rgb values with the pixel's alpha to reverse the prumultiplication… the formulas escalate quite quickly from here. Also subtract 1 from alpha because it's `OneMinusSrcAlpha`... and don't forget to check for cases where the sum of all alphas (yes, you need to sum that) is 0 (or in `OneMinusSrcAlpha` matter, something else), because otherwise you get division by 0 (or in `OneMinusSrcAlpha` matter a division by 0 when all surrounding pixels are solid). Also sometimes weird alpha values might work, but only for a single pass of blur, but in my case I have multiple passes.. etc.</sup>

Here's the final code:

***luminescence.frag***

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float threshold;

void main(void){
    vec3 current_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy).rgb;
    vec4 pixel =  vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    float brightness = dot(current_color.rgb, vec3(0.2126, 0.7152, 0.0722));
    if (brightness >= threshold){
        pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    }
    gl_FragColor = pixel;
}
```

***boxblur.frag***

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float texture_inverse;
uniform int blur_radius;
uniform vec2 blur_direction;

void main(void){
    vec4 sum = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);

    for (int i = 0; i < blur_radius; ++i){
        sum += texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + (i * texture_inverse) * blur_direction);
        sum += texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - (i * texture_inverse) * blur_direction);
    }
    gl_FragColor = sum / (blur_radius * 2 + 1);
}
```

***multiply.frag***

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float multiply;

void main(void){
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy) * multiply;
}
```

***assemble.frag***

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform sampler2D add_texture;
uniform float add_weight;

void main(void){
    vec4 tex_color = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    vec4 add_color = texture2D(add_texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy) * add_weight;
    gl_FragColor = tex_color + add_color;
}
```

***main.cpp***

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

void run() {
    const sf::Vector2f SIZE(1280, 720);

    sf::Texture background_tex;
    background_tex.loadFromFile("resources/background.jpg");
    sf::Sprite background(background_tex);

    sf::Shader luminescence_shader;
    luminescence_shader.loadFromFile("resources/luminescence.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    luminescence_shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    luminescence_shader.setUniform("threshold", 0.24f);

    sf::Shader blur_shader;
    blur_shader.loadFromFile("resources/boxblur.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    blur_shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    blur_shader.setUniform("texture_inverse", 1.0f / SIZE.x);

    sf::Shader assemble_shader;
    assemble_shader.loadFromFile("resources/assemble.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    assemble_shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);

    sf::Shader multiply_shader;
    multiply_shader.loadFromFile("resources/multiply.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment);
    multiply_shader.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);


    sf::RenderStates shader_states;
    //no blendmode! we make our own - assemble.frag

    sf::ContextSettings context_settings;
    context_settings.antialiasingLevel = 12;

    //draws background
    sf::RenderTexture scene_render;
    scene_render.create(SIZE.x, SIZE.y, context_settings);

    sf::RenderTexture luminescence_render;
    luminescence_render.create(SIZE.x, SIZE.y, context_settings);

    //draws luminescence and blur
    sf::RenderTexture assemble_render;
    assemble_render.create(SIZE.x, SIZE.y, context_settings);



    //addding multiple boxblurs with different radii looks really nice! in this case 4 layers
    std::array<sf::RenderTexture, 4> blur_renders;
    for (int i = 0; i < blur_renders.size(); ++i) {
        blur_renders[i].create(SIZE.x, SIZE.y, context_settings);
    }
    const int BLUR_RADIUS_VALUES[] = { 250, 180, 125, 55 };
    float blur_weight = blur_renders.empty() ? 0.0 : 1.0 / blur_renders.size();

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(SIZE.x, SIZE.y), "glsl fun", sf::Style::Default, context_settings);

    while (window.isOpen()) {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)) {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
                window.close();
            }
        }

        //first draw the scene
        scene_render.clear();
        scene_render.draw(background);
        scene_render.display();


        //apply luminescence
        shader_states.shader = &luminescence_shader;
        luminescence_render.clear();
        luminescence_render.draw(sf::Sprite(scene_render.getTexture()), shader_states);
        luminescence_render.display();

        //apply two pass gaussian blur n times to simulate gaussian blur.
        shader_states.shader = &blur_shader;
        for (int i = 0; i < blur_renders.size(); ++i) {
            blur_shader.setUniform("blur_radius", BLUR_RADIUS_VALUES[i]);

            blur_renders[i].clear();
            blur_renders[i].draw(sf::Sprite(luminescence_render.getTexture()));
            blur_renders[i].display();

            //vertical blur
            blur_shader.setUniform("blur_direction", sf::Glsl::Vec2(1.0, 0.0));
            blur_renders[i].draw(sf::Sprite(blur_renders[i].getTexture()), shader_states);
            blur_renders[i].display();

            //horizontal blur
            blur_shader.setUniform("blur_direction", sf::Glsl::Vec2(0.0, 1.0));
            blur_renders[i].draw(sf::Sprite(blur_renders[i].getTexture()), shader_states);
            blur_renders[i].display();
        }

        //load blur_renders[0] into assemble_render so we can add the other blurs ontop of it
        shader_states.shader = &multiply_shader;
        multiply_shader.setUniform("multiply", blur_weight);
        assemble_render.clear();
        assemble_render.draw(sf::Sprite(blur_renders[0].getTexture()), shader_states);
        assemble_render.display();

        //adding the rest ontop creating a final blur
        shader_states.shader = &assemble_shader;
        assemble_shader.setUniform("add_weight", blur_weight);
        for (int i = 1; i < blur_renders.size(); ++i) {
            assemble_shader.setUniform("add_texture", blur_renders[i].getTexture());
            assemble_render.draw(sf::Sprite(assemble_render.getTexture()), shader_states);
            assemble_render.display();
        }

        //final result; scene + blur
        assemble_shader.setUniform("add_weight", 1.0f);
        assemble_shader.setUniform("add_texture", assemble_render.getTexture());
        assemble_render.draw(sf::Sprite(scene_render.getTexture()), shader_states);
        assemble_render.display();

        window.clear();
        window.draw(sf::Sprite(assemble_render.getTexture()));
        window.display();
    }
}

int main() {
    try {
        run();
    }
    catch (std::exception e) {
        std::cerr << "caught exception - - - " << e.what() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: the 'multiply_shader' is missing. can you add it please

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a tiny example where you just want to average TWO pixels. Left (L) and right (R). Then the left pixel is made up of R(L), G(L), B(L), A(L) and the right pixel is made up of R(R), G(R), B(R) and A(R).

Without alpha, the averaging of Blue would just be:

```
(B(L)+B(R)) / 2
```

Taking alpha into account, it becomes:

```
(B(L)*A(L)+B(R)*A(R)) / (A(L)+A(R))
```

We can directly see that in the case of completely solid pixels (alpha=1) we get exactly the same formula as above:

```
(B(L)*1+B(R)*1) / (1+1)  =  (B(L)+B(R)) / 2
```

Furthermore, let's say that the right pixel is completely transparent and the left is solid, then the right pixel's color component won't affect anything, leaving the result exactly like the left pixel, which is exactly what we want:

```
(B(L)*1+B(R)*0) / (1+0)  =  (B(L)) / 1  = B(L)
```

Both pixels being completely transparent becomes a degenerate case which must be handled in some elegant way.

Now all you have to do is to extend this beyond two pixels. :-)

Comment: Oh thanks I understand, I will try to implement it now to see if it works!

Comment: Good luck! Please feel free to tell us here how it works! :-)

Comment: Also note that you should NOT blur the alpha channel itself. Kinda obvious, but an easy mistake to make.

Comment: It works for 1 pass of blur so far, (the blur is coloured, not White/Black/DarkBackgroundPixels) but for 2 passes e.g. the outer blur becomes White.. but I have some ideas. Let's see

Comment: Edit: I was wrong, even from 1 pass the edge is too bright.

Comment: Oh, that was unexpected... Are you, btw, working with RGB or PRGB (precomputed)? Just a thought... And the bright parts does not come from division by zero...? Can't think of anything more right now...

Comment: premultiplied rgb? yes, well I am turning it off and on right now, to be sure it doesn't affect the sitation. By the way, to calculate the Alpha it's (A(L) + A(R) / 2), right?

Comment: the Problem is, when I turn off the blendmode (which causes premultiplied rgb values), the blur is completely black even though that shouldn't be. I don't really understand it, but I think I will only achieve the Goal with it beeing turned off.

Comment: As I wrote earlier, you should not average the alpha itself... however, I realize that a glow effect needs to be able to expand into the transparent area, but this is unknown territory for me. *IF* the transparent area is made up of (0,1,1,1), that is "invisible white", I can easily understand why the edge becomes too bright when you raise it's alpha value. This is speculation... and I have no solution either right now (should it be the case).

Comment: Ok I got it! I posted this question on the sfml forum aswell and someone just told me how to do it. I am going to post the solution here in a few minutes